# Highcharts: multiple heatmaps with shared color bar

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

In Highcharts, is it possible to have multiple heatmaps in the same chart? For example, I would like to obtain something similar to the picture below:

[image]

I know I can make a chart for each heatmap and then align all the charts with CSS, but the thing is that I want the heatmaps to have a shared color bar.

Comment: You could create multiple charts with single color axis for each, every charts color axis would be set to hidden besides one, which you can position to be on the bottom of your charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create single chart and transform its data. Live example below.

```
$(function() {

  $('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
      type: 'heatmap',
      height: 1000,
      width: 1000
    },

    title: null,

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderColor: 'white'
        }
    },

    colorAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 1,
      minColor: 'white',
      maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[5]
    },

    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },

    xAxis: {
        visible: false
    },

    yAxis: {
        visible: false
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Sales per employee',
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [...Array(43*43)].map((u, i) => {
        const x = Math.floor(i/43) // Get x value from 0 to 42
        const y = i%43 // Get y value from 0 to 42
        const zeroX = !((x+1) % 9) || !((x+2) % 9) // if point should not be displayed
        const zeroY = !((y+1) % 9) || !((y+2) % 9) // if point should not be displayed
        const v = zeroX || zeroY ? 0 : Math.random() // if point should not be displayed then set its value to 0
        return [x, y, v] // return x y an value of each point
      })
    }]

  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k4dvz5r2/show/
[image]

Comment: That looks great. Could you explain what the transformation code is actually doing?

Comment: Hi, it is a simple data transformation. I added a description above.

Comment: Yes, that could be an idea. Actually I hoped there was some built-in feature for arranging multiple heatmaps in a single chart, without having to manually transform the data.. but anyway, yours can be a good solution.

Comment: stpoa - thanks, that helps. @George - there is not built in way to automatically arrange them. The "built in" way to achieve this in one chart is to specify a large array of multiple x and y axes. You could build a function to automate the layout based on the number of charts needed, etc, but there is not a property you can simply set to achieve it.